# Why can't I access The Reef?

Tags: destiny

I bought the expansion pass last month but I can't go to The Reef. The nightfall and weekly are all gone.

How do I go to The Reef?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. It's dealing with not being able to access content that hadn't launched at the time of the question being asked, but is now launched.

Comment: @Shaun I agree.

Answer (score 7):

The House of Wolves DLC does not go live until 10:00 AM PST today (May 19, 2015).  Until it goes live, the weekly and daily events (like Nightfall) will not refresh.  See Bungie's [blog post](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=12906) for more information.

Comment: He's right. Those parts will come back at 10am PST today.